# Is anyone concerned about Daenerys' lack of an heir?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Since only Bran and Howland Reed know about R+L=J as far as we know, Daenerys is kind of without an heir. Why does no one in the show seem concerned about this after season 1?

I mean, if she dies, everyone working for her kind of becomes unemployed right?

---

In the books how and when is concern over this brought up? What are proposed resolutions if any?

Comment: People not on Dany's side were concerned about her when she had an heir - Rhaego. They wanted to assassinate her, and her child. Now she doesn't have one (for slightly unrelated reasons). Everyone else on Dany's side is preoccupied with first taking the Iron Throne back before worrying about dynastic succession.

Comment: @DariM but if Daenerys dies suddenly everyone is unemployed right? Who do the dragons follow? What's to become of tyrion, grey worm, missandei, Jorah, daario, etc?

Comment: Related: [Is Daenerys Targaryen capable of conceiving a child?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/60198/21267) and [Why does Daenerys trust the prophecies of those who betray her?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/70515/21267)

Comment: They were. In *A Game of Thrones* (one of the Eddard chapters, I forget which), the Small Council is contemplating killing Dany especially when they find out that she is carrying Drogo's child (and might be a son). Ned strictly opposes this as he doesn't believe in killing children, as well as not killing one who might turn out to be a female and not pose much of a threat anyway.

Comment: You're correct though, the Meereenese arc hasn't concentrated on her legacy just yet. For now though, (in the books) she's married to [Hizdahr](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hizdahr_zo_Loraq), so people are probably just waiting for a child between them.

Comment: Don't forget also, that Dany strongly considers her Dragons to be her children, very publicly too. Additionally, "Mhysa" seems to be a "mother" to the people, so there's that.

Comment: @Mooz re hizdahr in books, post as answer?

Comment: Random unsullied are soldiers. They don't exactly have a stake in her "legacy". Someone like Tyrion (show) or Barristan (books) might, but it's sort of an academic point, especially since her availability for marriage could be a prominent point in making alliances in Westeros in the first place. A child with Hizdahr (or perhaps even Khal Drogo) would have been practically irrelevant, unless that child could also control the dragons.

Comment: @BCLC If she marries, her husband might have bastards that he can legitimize. Other than that, I guess you gave us the most obvious reason why Jon will sit on the Iron Throne :)

Comment: She may be intending to bring the current system of monarchy to an end.

Comment: Upon further thinking about this, this question doesn't seem to have an answer that isn't going to be opinion based or pure speculation. Voting for close.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42055/discussion-on-question-by-bclc-is-anyone-concerned-about-daenerys-lack-of-an-he).

Comment: Daario is concerned about Dany not having any heirs, and he has a solution as well.

Comment: If R + L = J becomes accepted, that still doesn't give Daenerys an heir. It makes her King Jon's heir.

Comment: Since you decided to call me out, the relevance of my answer is because you're asking the question "Is anyone concerned with Dany not having an heir?" That's your question. Which my answer satisfies. However, as I stated, this is going to be very opinion based, and thus should be closed.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks: Well, if you think the question is off-topic, you shouldn't answer it :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the answer was deleted as soon as the off-topic opinion was formulated I guess

Answer (score 7):

Dany's a little busy right now being kidnapped by Dothraki, riding dragonback and invading a continent.

As she alludes to when dumping Daario, once she's set up in Westeros she'll be looking to marry for political reasons; this will traditionally result in an heir.

But, while you're right in that it's important to have a successor, there's really not much point rushing into that now. If she dies, do you think the Unsullied are just going to stand around for 20 years waiting for her kid to go on the warpath? It's debatable that they'd be any better off if she already had a baby.

As an aside, if Daenerys is reading this and *does* decide she needs an heir, well, I'm available.

Comment: shes also what 15/6 now? lol

Comment: @Himarm: Well, to be fair, she's had a kid before and that was six years ago!

Comment: has it been 6 years inthe book though? its been 6 seasons, but the show even its only been a year or 2 ibelieve!

Comment: @Himarm: Perhaps so.

Comment: Well at least tyrion, grey worm, missandei etc have someone for whom to fight. Tyrion/they can rule as regent or overthrow the monarchy or idk. The whole point of having an heir early is for backups in case of deaths which in this case are pretty likely right?

Comment: @BCLC: "Backups"? A child isn't a clone. Right now they want magical _Daenerys_ to rule, not "any available Targaryen". Wasting time on childbirth does not advance anyone's goals here at this point.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If employer has children, employees won't become unemployed if employer dies, in this case. Wrong?

Comment: @BCLC: I think you're seeing it as if being in Dany's massive army is like working at a shoe shop. It's not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what do you mean? I don't think you answered my question but then again i guess you're saying that I'm asking a wrong question

Comment: He means you're vastly oversimplifying the dynamics of the situation. First, the Unsullied are freed slaves who have chosen to fight for the person who freed them. Random 1-year old baby doesn't quite foster the same loyalty. Secondly, Daenerys' will to the Iron Throne is what drives her to direct an army there. Random 1-year old baby doesn't have that. You're acting as if people around Daenerys somehow need her to have a child to have "something to do", when their loyalties and relevance is to Daenerys herself.

Comment: Yeah, that. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In the books Daenerys is quite young, about 16 Y/o so there is plenty of time for her to conceive a heir. And the world is (or was) quite interested in that, Robert sent assassins when he heard she was pregnant.

So for a while it was no concern, since it was kinda fixed that "eventually" she was going to marry someone and have a heir.

> She was going to marry Griff/Aegon according to Varys' plan and thus, consolidate the Targaryen/Blackfyre Dynasty

but right now in the books THAT is one of the major concerns.

> In Meeren, there is no clear "heir" to Dany.  Hizdahr zo Loraq is her husband, but he does not have the support of the rest of the council.

Answer (score 0):

To address your main question about whether anyone is worried about it well Tyrion appears to worry and finally mentions his concerns in season 7 episode 6.

> Tyrion Lannister: How do we ensure your vision endures? After you break the wheel, how do we make sure it stays broken?
>   Daenerys Targaryen: You want to know who sits on the Iron Throne after I'm dead?
>   Tyrion Lannister: You say you can't have children. But there are other ways of choosing a successor. The Night's Watch has one method, The Iron born folk, although many flaws...
>   Daenerys Targaryen: We will discuss the succession after I wear the crown.
>   Tyrion Lannister: Your Grace, I saw hundreds of arrows fly towards you when you fought on Blackwater Rush, and I saw hundred of arrows miss. But any one of them could have found your heart and end.
>   Daenerys Targaryen: You've been thinking about my death quite a bit, haven't you? Is this one of the items you've discussed with your brother in King's Landing?
>   Tyrion Lannister: I'm trying to serve you by planning for the long term.
>   Daenerys Targaryen: Perhaps if you'd planned for the short term, we wouldn't have lost Dorne and Highgarden. We will discuss the succession after I wear the crown.
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 7 Episode 6, "Beyond the Wall"</sub>

As for why most people aren't worried well I think it's answered perfectly well enough by Dany herself in the above quote:

- She can't have children (maybe she can but she believes she can't)
- There's no point in deciding it and working it all out if they're unsuccessful anyway

---

<sup>On a side note I think Jorah has been worried about the matter from very early on.</sup>

Comment: Does your answer shed light on previous seasons? Otherwise, I think you cheated...

Comment: No it adds new information, we do that all the time to old questions/answers. I don't really understand what cheated means here but the OP has no restrictions on seasons only past season 1 which this is.

Comment: Lol I am OP. You're answering based on episodes after the date OP posted OP wherein I guess the answer does not shed light on previous episodes. It sounds like saying I should have bought a stock based on its price today. It wouldn't be (that much of) cheating if the price today was somehow shedding some light on previous stock prices.